# Relation between the dimension of a Lie Algebra and the dimension of its complexified version

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Suppose $L$ is a semi-simple Lie Algebra with dimension $d$. The complexification of the Lie Algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ is given by $$L_{\mathbb{C}} = L \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$$

My question is: in general is there a way to determine the dimension of the complexification knowing the dimension of the original Lie Algebra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Lie algebras. It's a general basic fact of linear algebra and scalar extensions that if $E \vert K$ is any field extension and $V$ is any vector space over $K$, then

$$\dim_E (E \otimes_K V) = \dim_K(V).$$

More precisely, if $\{v_i: i \in I\}$ is any $K$-basis of $V$, then $\{1 \otimes v_i : i\in I\}$ is an $E$-basis of $E \otimes_K V$. Any source which introduces tensor products should mention if not prove these facts.

Answer (score 1):

"My question is: in general is there a way to determine the dimension of the complexification knowing the dimension of the original Lie Algebra?"

**Answer:** If $L$ is a real Lie algebra of dimension $d$, it follows $L*:=L\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{C}^d$. Hence $L*$ has dimension $d$.

**Comment:** "could you expand on why L⊗RC≅Cd?"

**Answer:** The Lie algebra $L$ has a basis over the reals:

$$L \cong \mathbb{R}\{e_1,..,e_d\}$$

and it follows

$$L \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}\{e_1,..,e_d\}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}^d.$$

Comment: could you expand on why $L\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{C}^d$?